# Ursina Python Engine: Question about the Lighting System

Tags: python, game-engine, shadow, lighting, ursina

I saw this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nrmn.png) on the official [Ursina Engine Webiste](https://www.ursinaengine.org) and wanted to ask if this is even possible. If so, how?

I would appreciate any information that could be helpful.

I played around with the lighting options for a few hours, but the only thing I got working was shadows with the directional light. Additionally, I wasn't able to find any more information in the [Official Documentation](https://www.ursinaengine.org/api_reference.html#Light).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot you linked is actually from the `projector_shader` in `ursina/shaders/projector_shader.py`. It's not actually light, but is in this example used to give the illusion of light by using a "vignette" texture. There are no shadows for example. There's no vertical falloff either.